# Adding multiple PHP jobs into 1 crob job

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I have a limit of 5 cron jobs on my hosting account which has multiple sites. So i need to split all the jobs over 5 sets of cron jobs. The files being called are all related to the wordpress plugin, feedwordpress and in the format

```
/usr/bin/curl --silent http://unique_website.com?update_feedwordpress=1
```

So I plan on having 5 cron jobs each calling 5 of these sites to update. Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could just write a script that executes all of your curl requests.

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/curl --silent http://unique_website.com?update_feedwordpress=1
/usr/bin/curl --silent http://unique_website.com?update_feedwordpress=2
/usr/bin/curl --silent http://unique_website.com?update_feedwordpress=3
```

And change your your cron task to execute that script instead.

Comment: I havent worked with sh before, what would i put into the file?(sorry i know thats a lame question. I addition from the cron on my host would i the point it to:    /usr/bin/curl --silent http://unique_website.com/cron.sh

Comment: This code should be all you have to put in the file. The cron job should `/bin/sh /path/to/script.sh` or possibly `/bin/bash /path/to/script.sh`. If you can make the script executable you can probably get by with making it simply `/path/to/script.sh`

Answer (score 1):

You could also do something like

```
/usr/bin/curl --silent --config /path/to/your/config
```

And have your config file look like

```
#Update wordpress #1
url = 'http://unique_website.com?update_feedwordpress=1'

#Update wordpress #2
url = 'http://unique_website.com?update_feedwordpress=2'

#more ...
```

which has the advantage of being "fire and forget" for the cronjob, if you need changes just change the config file. Ofcourse you could also write your config file from PHP

Answer (score 1):

btw with curl you can do any of these things:

```
/usr/bin/curl --silent http://unique_website.com?update_feedwordpress=[1-5]
/usr/bin/curl --silent http://unique_website.com?update_feedwordpress={1,2,3,5}
/usr/bin/curl --silent http://{unique,other,third}_website.com?update_feedwordpress=1
```

And it will call curl multiple times with different parameters